# how to change start and end date on an ics file

Tags: google-calendar-api, icalendar

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
PRODID:adamgibbons/ics
METHOD:PUBLISH
X-PUBLISHED-TTL:PT1H
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:k69yTZB7_n8S4_UDFWRUZ
SUMMARY:Information Security Analysis and Audit (ETH)
DTSTAMP:20230502T063200Z
DTSTART:20220721T123000Z
DESCRIPTION:BCSE353E
LOCATION:SMV121RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20221122T233000Z
DURATION:PT50M
END:VEVENT
```

THIS is part of ics file produced by an online timetable parser(created by one of our alumni) which gives me my course time table but the problem with it is that it is not updated (for this semester) and so all the start and end dates are of my previous semester subjects now I want to change the start and end dates of all my course events how do I do that.

I tried manually replacing `DTSTART:20220721T123000Z` with `DTSTART:20230503T123000Z` In VScode
but after everything was done it said file corrupted